# Python ImportError: No module named

Tags: python

Есть файл с "конфигурацией" из которого берутся переменные

Файл - **__main__.py**

```
import sys
import getopt
import os
import picamera
from raspm import raspm

camera = None
camlock = Lock()

USAGE = '''
Usage %s [OPTIONS] COMMAND

COMMANDS:
    run  -- Start RPM as Raspberry Pi Manager (default)
    http-server -- Start only http server


CONFIGURATION:
    - Configuration specified on the command line
    - /etc/rpm.conf
    - ./etc/rpm.conf

'''

def usage(retval = 0):
    print(USAGE % sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(retval)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    cfg = '/etc/rpm.conf' if os.path.isfile('/etc/rpm.conf') else './etc/rpm.conf'

    try:
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='8080')
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'hc:' ['help', 'config='])
    finally:
        #After work is finished shut off the camera
        with camlock:
            if camera:
                camera.close()
```

Файл -
    raspm.py

```
....

def update_configuration(cfgfile):
    from configobj import ConfigObj
    from raspm.config import cfgspec
    from validate import Validator
    cfg = ConfigObj(cfgfile, configspec=cfgspec)
    validator = Validator()
    cfg.validate(validator)
    globals()['CONFIG'] = cfg
    return cfg

# Set up configuration
CONFIG = update_configuration('/etc/rpm.conf')

...
```

Далее конфиг файл config.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Default configuration.
'''

__CFG = '''
 ......
'''

cfgspec = __CFG.split('\n')
```

И последний rpm.conf

При запуске **__main__.py**
Получаю следующие:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__main__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from raspm import raspm
  File "/home/pi/python-RPi-camera-controll/raspm/raspm.py", line 73, in <module>
    CONFIG = update_configuration('./etc/rpm.conf')
  File "/home/pi/python-RPi-camera-controll/raspm/raspm.py", line 64, in update_configuration
    from rpm.config import cfgspec
ImportError: No module named rpm.config
```

файлы в папках:

```
python/
 - etc/
 - - rpm.conf
 - raspm/
 - - __main__.py
 - - config.py
 - - raspm.py
```

Так и не пойму в чем проблема

Comment: Очевидно, в том, что нет модуля rpm.config :) А откуда его взять и что вообще за модуль такой rpm, мне и гуглу неизвестно

Comment: @andreymal но ведь по этому что у меня в коде, rpm.config должен браться из папки

Comment: Подозреваю, нужна полная информация о папках и всех файлах в них

Comment: @andreymal обновил вопрос - добавил информации

Comment: Эх, нет, никаких намёков на модуль rpm всё ещё не видно

Comment: Мне остаётся лишь предположить, что имеет место опечатка и имеется в виду raspm вместо rpm

Comment: @andreymal `rpm.conf` - он ведь.

Comment: rpm.conf это не модуль, а текстовый фаил, его никак нельзя импортировать

Comment: @andreymal я видел похожее здесь https://github.com/lkiesow/pyCA/tree/master/pyca и пытаюсь добится того же

Comment: А вот надо не "добиваться того же", а разбираться в сути, как всё устроено и почему работает. Доберусь до компьютера - расскажу в чате, если меня не опередят. Но всё же и там никаких текстовых файлов не импортируют :)

Comment: @andreymal тогда буду ждать и постараюсь что нибудь еще другое придумать )

Comment: Вот хороший пример плохого кода. Все импорты должны быть явно вынесены в начало сценариев. Сами себе костылей наделают, а потом гадают, откуда взялся Lock() и почему ImportError?

Comment: Если вышепредложенное ещё актуально, то покажите мне кто-нибудь, где из этого вопроса чат создать)

Comment: @andreymal еще актуально ) По идеи, оно само пишет, что лучше создать чат, чем засорять комментариями. Нажимаешь и создает.

Comment: Эх, нет, не пишет

Comment: @andreymal есть у вас другой способ для связи?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
File "/home/pi/python-RPi-camera-controll/raspm/raspm.py", line 64, in update_configuration
    from rpm.config import cfgspec
ImportError: No module named rpm.config
```

В файле raspm.py (64 строка) должно быть:

```
from raspm.config import cfgspec
```

В папку `raspm/` положить (пустой) файл `__init__.py`

---

```
.
├── f1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── pf1.py
├── f2
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── pf2.py
└── main.py
```

main.py:

```
from f1.pf1 import fun1
fun1()
```

pf1.py:

```
from f2.pf2 import fun2
def fun1():
    print "I am fun1"
    fun2()
```

pf2.py:

```
def fun2():
    print "I am fun2"
```

выполняем:

```
$ python main.py
I am fun1
I am fun2
```

---

Как-то так работает импорт из подпапок в Python.
Ну и согласен, все импорты - в начале файла.

Comment: Импорт из подпапок в Python работает и без __init__.py. Достаточно указать путь к директории в sys.path.

Comment: @Xyanight, хммм... Все подпапки текущего проекта в sys.path писать? Можно, но зачем?

Comment: @Xyanight тогда импортируемый файл получится не подмодулем модуля, а самим модулем, что не всегда приемлемо